# Oracle adf form not resetting new data from iterator

Tags: oracle-adf

I have an issue with oracle adf form that always keeping same data in form from an iterator. Even though i am resetting the data but its still keeps same data when we come back from previous page with table of an iterator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you come back to the form, along with resetting the data you have to re-execute the iterator and do partial triggers on the table and the form.

When you re-execute the iterator the cursor will be pointing to the before first row and the partial triggers on table and form will be refreshed based on the current row in iterator (before first row = no row selected).

To give more specific inputs, how you are coming back to this form? if you share code snippet of jsff and the bean then it will be easy to suggest the solution.